# Mockito on Android, Context.getString(id) and NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I've just started learning a Mockito testing framework, I followed official tutorial from: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html)

The code is:

```
private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

@Mock
Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
    // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
    when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_world))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
    ClassUnderTest myObjectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mMockContext);

    // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
    String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

    // ...then the result should be the expected one.
    assertThat(result, is(FAKE_STRING));
}
```

I wrote following ClassUnderTest:

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

private Context context;

public ClassUnderTest(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
}

public String getHelloWorldString()
{
    return context.getString(R.string.hello_world);
}
```

}

and after running I'm getting NullPointerException:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.Context.getHelloWorldString(Context.java:293)
at com.darekk.draggablelistview.unit_tests.MockitoTest.readStringFromContext_LocalizedString(MockitoTest.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
```

When I replace android Context with my own class it works.

Platform: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.6

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the exact code from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies).  Apparently they posted an incomplete example.. add this method to your test:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

For further reference checkout [Mockito's docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9)

Answer (score 7):

This code should be the first line of Your test:

```
doReturn("Sample Hello world string")
            .when(mMockContext)
            .getString(any(Integer.class));
```

A stubbing of a method is needed

Comment: Hmm, should I put it inside getHelloWorldString() method? where exactly?, It's strange. I thought only Context.getString(...) should be stubbed.

Comment: Edited my answer. No need to modify class under test.

Comment: I have this: when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_world))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);

Comment: I tried your solution, but any(Integer.class) cannot be resolved, so I used anyInt() instead and got another error:  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Comment: Yes, the reason there should be `anyInt()` is that you stub a method that has `int` parameter. You could pass any integer parameter and method call will be stubbed by Mockito.

Comment: The last error is connected with incorrect `assertThat` call. With objects annotated with Mockito You can only check interactions with it (whether a method was invoked or not): `verify(mMockContext).getString`.
It is a better test practice to create a real test model, rather than mock it. It's dependencies should be mocked.

Comment: Ok, replaced assertThat() with verify(), and got: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:String cannot be returned by getResources()
getResources() should return Resources. If you know how to do it correctly, please edit your answer with complete working example.

Comment: There is no difference between your solution and what the poster already had `when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_world)).thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

Context.getString() is a final method so you CANNOT mock it by default using Mockito. 
To enabling mocking of final methods you need Mockito v2 and follow the instructions here
[Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)

> create a file in `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:
>
> ```
> mock-maker-inline
> ```

Once you do this you can mock getString() `when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.string_name)).thenReturn("Mocked String");`

Comment: This is incorrect. Per the Android documentation:

"At runtime, [local unit] tests are executed against a modified version of android.jar where all final modifiers have been stripped off. This lets you use popular mocking libraries, like Mockito."

See https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#test_types_and_location

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in your build.gradle file

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock:1.6.5"
```

Than run above code, it will start working.